# Присвоение введенных данных новой переменной

Tags: c++

Я создал список. Дело в следующем: Я хочу чтобы каждое введенное мной значение присваивалось каждый раз новой переменной. Приблизительно так: х1, х2, ... хn. Но чтобы потом я мог их использовать, например х5 + х55 и т.д Как нумеровать так "х"? Но чтобы он автоматически присваивал индексы. Надеюсь смог донести свой замысел вам. Если нет то просьба уточните у меня. Сам пытался, но ничего в голову не приходило. Без использования массива.

Comment: @navi1893, если правильно понял, то у Вас не получается присвоить элементам списка, который Вы  строите, последовательные номера в списке.

Для этого в структуре, описывающей весь список, заведите поле, скажем, int maxnum и при создании списка обнулите его. В структуре элемента списка, соответственно д.б. поле int num. 

Когда добавляете новый элемент в список, присваивайте num = maxnum++.

Что-то в таком духе. Потом по этим номерам можно искать в списке (но только последовательно).

Comment: а если я сделаю ,num = max++, то я же не смогу произвольно взять пятый элемент и 100-ый например. Нет? Сама задача в следующем: у меня список, типа string. И у меня одна лишь переменная Х. Каждый раз я ввожу значение Х и он добавляется в список и выводится. Но вот мне щас надо, чтобы взять какой то элемент, например пятый и приписать его к 20-му. Но я не знаю, как мне выбрать тот самый пятый и 20-ый элементы, чтобы работать с ними. Вот в чем моя проблема вся. Что посоветуете мне?

Comment: Если нужно обращаться к данным по индексу, то список не годится, надо использовать массив (vector). Но, быстро выбираете - медленно удаляете (включаете в начало или середину) и т.п.

Вообще же, выбор структуры данных (архитектуры) зависит от частоты операций доступа того или иного вида  к элементам данных в **конкретной** задаче.

Опишите задачу *в целом*. Вы задаете вопросы по каким-то частным случаям. В результате Вы получаете правильные, но unconsistent ответы.

Comment: Вот сама задача:    Требуется реализовать возможность работы со строками произвольной длины. Строка хранится отдельными кусками фиксированной длины, которые связаны в список и добавляются или удаляются по мере необходимости.
  Реализация класса должна поддерживать след. возможности:
1) Создать пустой буфер
2) Добавить заданную строку в конец буфера
3) Вставить заданную строку с заданной позиции буфера
4) Получить длину строки, накопленной в буфере
5) Скопировать строку в заданный символьный массив
6) Получить\изменить символ в заданной позиции
7) Заменить одну подстроку на другую в буфере

Comment: Сделайте обертку (свой класс) над [вектор](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)

Answer (score 1):

Вы почти правильно описали. Немного некорректно. В массиве данные расположены по индексам и имеют определённую ячейку памяти, в которой хранят значение. Обращаться к ним можно по индексу (e.g. `A[индекс]`), так же как и выполнять действия (`A[индекс1]+A[индекс2]`). Вот простой пример считывания из файла значений в массив.

```
int sizeA;          //Размеры вектора
ifstream in("in.txt");  //Инициализируем чтение файла in.txt
if (!in) {          //Если есть ошибка чтения
    cout << "Error reading file data" << endl;  //Уведомим
    return 1;
}
in >> sizeA;                            //Считываем размер вектора А
int A[sizeA];                           //Инициализируем вектор заданного размера
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeA - 1; i++) {  //Для всех элементов массива
    in >> A[i];                         //Считываем из файла
}
```

Так же вы можете использовать вектора (`std::vector<int> A;`) с соответствующими методами (push_back,insert, etc.)

Comment: а как же мне сделать, чтобы без массива было. Потому что если я буду пользоваться массивом, то это же уже не будет работа со списком и классом, а будет работа с массивом только. Мне нужно без массива как то найти выход из положения.

Comment: Прямо скажу, это ответ не на данный вопрос. TC спрашивает, как ему именовать элементы **списка** (он имеет в виду *связный список*). 

При чем здесь массив или vector ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Самый простой способ:  
int arr[256];
for(int i = 0; i<=256; i++)
cin >> arr[i];
```